# How to Create a Stylish progress bar and use it

Tags: c#, winforms, progress-bar

I want to create a stylish progress bar like this and i want to use it

[image]

i dont know how to create this progress bar and use it.

I want to use it because it is very good for my application.

There would be a great appreciation if someone could help me.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Do you mean you want to change colours and have a different look?

Comment: This style of the progress bar is intended for tasks with undetermined duration. Are you sure that's the best thing for your needs ? (It may mislead your users)

Comment: yes i need it just when my code reads database file and after it is finished it should be close

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just set this property!

```
progressBar1.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee;
```